# Angular : Receive responses in order with the calls

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, observable, subject

Hi I am pretty new to Angular and Observables

I am trying to GET Objects by theirs ID through a loop.
But don't receive my Response in Order.

Example

```
get ID(1)
get ID(2)
get ID(3)
Receive Object ID(2)
Receive Object ID(3)
Receive Object ID(1)
```

Is it possible to get my Objects back in order ??
Below is where I call multiple times my service function :

```
conferences-attendance.component.ts
```

```js
  ExportExcelAttendance() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.contactsAttendance.length; i++) {
      this.practiceService.GetPracticebyDBID(this.contactsAttendance[i].practiceId)
        .subscribe(
        (practice: Practice) => {
          this.practicesAttendance.push(practice);
          if (this.practicesAttendance.length == this.contactsAttendance.length) {
            this.ExportExcelAttendance2();
          }
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }
  }
```

Here is my function in my service, it where I receive the data (not in order with the calls).

```
practices.service.ts
```

```js
    GetPracticebyDBID(id: string) {
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('thisId', id);
        let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.params = params;
        return this.http.get('http://ec2-34-231-196-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com/getpractice', requestOptions)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json().obj;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forkJoin` gives you a little less code,

```js
const arrayOfFetches = this.contactsAttendance
  .map(attendee => this.practiceService.GetPracticebyDBID(attendee.practiceId) );

Observable.forkJoin(...arrayOfFetches)
  .subscribe((practices: Practice[]) => {
      this.practicesAttendance = practices;
      this.ExportExcelAttendance2();
  });
```

**Edit**
Snap! @Anas beat me to it. Although, I don't think you need the `concatAll()`

Comment: I agree, but decided to keep `cocncatAll` as well, sometimes you need your API calls to run in sequence. ex: signup then login.

Comment: @AnasAlHamdan - good point! Although, I was referring to concatAll following forkJoin, which you since removed (presume a copy-paste thing).

Comment: you caught me :p

Answer (score 2):

you should use [concatAll](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/concatall.html) operator to ensure calling your observables in sequence.

also, you can use `completed` callback to call `ExportExcelAttendance2` instead of checking `practicesAttendance` length on every response callback.

check the below example:

```
let contactsAttendanceObservables = this.contactsAttendance
  .map((item) => {
    return this.practiceService.GetPracticebyDBID(item.practiceId);
  });
Observable.of(...contactsAttendanceObservables)
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(
    (practice: Practice) => {
      this.practicesAttendance.push(practice);
    },
    (err) => {
      // handle any errors.
    },
    () => {
      // completed
      this.ExportExcelAttendance2();
    }
  );
```

if you still want your observables to run in parallel, you can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) Operator, which will emit the last value of all the passed observables to a one subscriber when all observables are completed.

check the below example:

```
let contactsAttendanceObservables = this.contactsAttendance
  .map((item) => {
    return this.practiceService.GetPracticebyDBID(item.practiceId);
  });
Observable.forkJoin(...contactsAttendanceObservables)
  .subscribe(
    (practices: Practice[]) => {
      this.practicesAttendance = practices;
      this.ExportExcelAttendance2();
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! What does mean ... in Observable.of(...contactsAttendanceObservables). As well what

Comment: here you go: Spread syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: I got an error with [ts] Argument of type '(completed: any => void is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.

Comment: my bad, check the updated answer, or use forkJoin for faster responses since it will allow observables execution parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The `forkJoin operator` is simple to use. It waits until all observables complete, then emit an array with all the items emitted.

```js
ExportExcelAttendance() {
  const all = this.contactsAttendance.map(it => this.practiceService.GetPracticebyDBID(it.practiceId));
  Rx.Observable.forkJoin(all)
    .subscribe(
      practicesAttendance => this.ExportExcelAttendance2(practicesAttendance),
      error => this.errorMessage = < any > error);
}
```